# Undefined local variable or method `question_params' despite it being defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm practicing TDD with CRUD and am running into this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `question_params' for #<QuestionsController:0x0000010618a248>
```

Here are my specs (though I think they're irrelevant):

```
 describe '#create'  do
   it 'assigns @question to a new question' do
     post :create
     expect(assigns(:question)).to be_a_new(Question)
   end

   it 'redirects to the question once created' do
     post :create
     expect(response).to redirect_to question_path(@question)
   end
 end
```

Here is the controller:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @question = Question.new 
  end

  def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.new(question_params) 

    if @question.save
      redirect_to @question
    else
      render :new
    end

    private

    def question_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:title, :body)
    end
  end
end
```

What's the deal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `question_params` within the other method `create`. It should look like this:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @question = Question.new 
  end

  def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.new(question_params) 

    if @question.save
      redirect_to @question
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

private

  def question_params
    params.require(:question).permit(:title, :body)
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh gosh. **Facepalm**

Answer (score 1):

Your ends don't line up. The create method currently includes the question_params method.

Try this:

```
def create
  @question = Question.new(question_params) 

  if @question.save
    redirect_to @question
  else
    render :new
  end
end

private

def question_params
  params.require(:question).permit(:title, :body)
end
```